# Word Editor Find pattern

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, outlook, ms-word

I am facing a situation dealing with Microsoft Word's Find feature.
I have the following code which works in matching the text of patterns like ASAss12345 or ASAhg76543 etc.

```
uiFind.Text = "ASA^$^$^#^#^#^#^#"
```

;

But this pattern also matches occurrences like **exampleASAjj76543** and also **ASAjj78987sample**
But I need to match patterns containing only **ASAss12345**

I know to do this in usual regex like "\bASA^$^$^#^#^#^#^#\b". But, how can I do the same when using word editor property in Outlook 2007?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
\bASA[a-z]{2}\d[0-9]*$
```

**Edit:**
This one is for Word

```
<ASA[a-z]{2}[0-9]{5}>
```

Comment: He's using Word Find, not a regex.

Comment: I tried the word one you posted. This does not match the normal pattern itself. I also tried "<ASA^$^$^#^#^#^#^#>"